# Python program to create and display all combinations of letters, selecting each letter from a different key in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have this dictionary below:

```
d ={'1':['a','b'], '2':['c','d']}
```

I need to combine the values of it by using for- loop to become as below:

The expected results:

```
ac                                                                                                            
ad                                                                                                            
bc                                                                                                            
bd
```

This is my poor try and I couldn't continue, How can I do it?

My try:

```
dic = {'1':['a','b'], '2':['c','d']}   
for x ,y in dic.values():
    print(x,y)
```

My output:

```
a b
c d
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
from itertools import product

d ={'1':['a','b'], '2':['c','d']}

for x, y in product(*d.values()):
    print(x + y)
```

**Output:**

```
ac
ad
bc
bd
```

The manual nested loop way would be something like this:

```
for x in d['1']:
    for y in d['2']:
        print(x + y)
```

Comment: This answers the question as OP posed it correctly. I don't know why OP wants a Cartesian product of strings though.

Answer (score 0):

```
my_dict= {'1':['a', 'b'], '2':['c', 'd'}}
my_list= list(my_dict.values())
for i in my_list[0]:
    for j in my_list[1]:
        print(i+j)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].